# How do I customize the timeshift parameter of the delay subtitle keyboard shortcut in VLC?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vlc-media-player, subtitles

I always use subtitles when watching movies/TV shows, and kept using BSPlayer just because of the keyboard shortcuts it offers to tweak the subtitles on the fly. And I use these shortcuts *a lot*.

For instance if they are slightly delayed, there is a shortcut to delay them +/-200ms at a time (most of the time, this is perfect for the granularity I'm looking for). If it's a larger delay, another shortcut can delay them +/-1 sec at a time (and then once I'm in roughly the good spot, I can switch back to +/-200ms to fine tune it).

If there is an audio delay, another shortcut can delay audio +/-100ms at a time.

But I want to use VLC because BSPlayer is just a shitty video player otherwise. However with VLC I can only customize the keybinds, and not the functions themselves.

VLC only offers a single shortcut for subtitle delay, and it shifts 50ms at a time. 2 questions:

1. Can I create another one that shifts 1sec at a time, and how?
2. If I can't, can I at least adjust the existing shortcut so that it shifts 200ms and not 50ms?
3. Same question as 2) for audio delay which is also by default set to 50ms

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

To change in VLC the subtitle delay, go to menu
*Tools > Track Synchronization*,
and set the delay in "Subtitle track syncronization".
The up button will let you delay the subtitle speed.

It's also possible to change other subtitle parameters in the same dialog,
such as duration time and more.

If you close VLC, you will need to set it again.